# Update Group Policy via Batch Script or Powershell Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, powershell, group-policy, batch

I administer about 300 remote computers (all across the country) that are on Windows 7 Pro (32-bit) and I need to change the Group Policy.  This is the first time in 5 years I've had to change the GP.  I've gone into MMC and used gpedit for that user's policy and made the changes I needed, then saved it.  But how do I apply those changes to those computers?  I can only access the PCs via the command line using SSH.  When I've had to update them, I create a batch script that gets pushed to all those PCs to run overnight.  Sometimes, I've created Powershell scripts and run the Powershell scripts via the Batch updates.

Best way to apply the Group Policy changes via Batch Script (command line) or Powershell?

Comment: If you are using Local Group Policy instead of Active Directory Group Policy you should specify that.  Microsoft has a tool, Local Group Policy Utility (LGPO), that is part of the Security Compliance Toolkit. LGPO can be used for managing and importing Local Group Policy settings.  See: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55319

Comment: @GregAskew It is LGPO.  But what I need to know is whether there is did I create a new .pol file somewhere when I made my changes?  Do I want to include that with my batch file and run UpdateLGPO.exe with that .pol file?

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine`